# Insert grid data to database

Tags: database, extjs

It seems that this should be something very easy, but I dont see any data in it on the web.

I have a grid, in which the user can change its values.

Now all I want to do is update/insert the new values in to my db.

How can I do that without sending an ajax?

```
var temp = '';
for (i=0; i<=checkboxSelection.length-1; i++){
    temp = temp + checkboxSelection[i].get('vendor_name') + ","
           + checkboxSelection[i].get('vendor_value') + ";";
}

Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: 'foo',
    params: {
    vendors: temp
    }
});
```

Comment: What do you mean "without sending an ajax"?

Comment: Use AJAX or use a form.

Comment: In my program i used an ajax as writen in the example, but that just doesnt seems right, is that a right way to do it? in my .jsp file i split the values again and than do the work. But is that the way to do it? doesn.t seem so. I saw the form example, its looks like might be what i need, is that the more suggested way for doing it?

Comment: if you want to save grid data to database, you need to use store. http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.Store